# Will iOS6 receives silent push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app wors from iOS5 - iOS8.

I want to implement silent push notification. Now I know silent push notification available starting from iOS7 and above. as per below code :

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    }
}
```

if I receive silent push notification in iOS6 and below, will my app receive push notification or it doesn't do anything ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is NO. The notification will not received by the device.
As mentioned in Apple documentation here -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

The Callback method is available only from iOS7

Comment: so iOS6 and below won't get any notifications ?